# Do touchstone (s2p) files for capacitors from include the ESR/ESL, or do I need to add an ideal R/L for simulation?

Tags: capacitor, simulation, bias, esr, derating

Manufacturers like muRata and AVX provide .s2p files for their RF capacitors.

When modeling for simulation in my EDI software, do I need to include the ESR graphed in the datasheet for the frequency we are using as an ideal resistor component, or does the s2p file already embed the ESR (and ESL) in its metrics?

For examle, do I need the C1_ESR and C1_ESL components if I an using an s2p file?

[image: Capacitor ESR ESL]

What about capacitor DC-bias derating?  Are touchstone files even capable of understanding the presence of a DC bias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the vendor supplied S2P file will contain the effects of ESR and ESL. The model used will be somewhat more complicated than just a simple RLC combination, accounting for current crowding in certain parts of the capacitor structure as frequency increases.

If they didn't include these effects (i.e. if they just modeled an ideal capacitor of a given value) there wouldn't be much point to having the vendor supply the S2P file instead of just using an ideal capacitor in your circuit model.

Comment: what about DC-bias derating?

Comment: @KJ7LNW, you'll have to check with the vendors on that. If you're getting your Murata files from the SimSurfing tool, it does let you set the DC bias before downloading, and generates a different file depending on that setting.

Comment: Neat! I didn't realize SimSurfing changed the s2p based on the bias. I'm noticing that while both AVX and Murata provide bulk downloads of their s2p files, they only provide those files in about the 1-100pF range.  Is there an industry reason that they don't provide s2p's above 100pF?

Comment: @KJ7LNW, those might be the values most interesting for RF work. But when I was checking on it just now I used 100 nF as an example and was able to get the files.

Comment: It looks like at least AVX provides large values in their design tools (like for Microwave Office) but not in their bulk s2p .zip download.  I guess if anyone else finds this looking for larger s2p values: find the design package for your EDI software from the cap vendor and go from there.